# Node.js - Set default local variables to pass into layout/template

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I'm using Node.js and Express, and I want to pass a local variable in to the layout on every page, is there any way to do this? I'm using Jade as my templating engine.

The reason I want this is because I want to display the user's username on every page (using session), any way to do this other than including it every time in the local object?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can achieve this by defining a dynamic view helper, as pointed out in the official [Express guide](http://expressjs.com/guide.html):

```
app.dynamicHelpers({
  session: function(req, res){
    return req.session;
  }
});
```

Then in your views you can simply access the `session` variable, and for example session.user to display the user.